# Fingerprint scanner browser support

Tags: chrome, firefox, fingerprint

I need to implement fingerprint scanning for all the users in a secure web app.

Do fingerprint reader support chrome or firefox? From my google search they all seems to only be supported by IE. All the users use chrome or firefox...

Will I be better off make the users use the integrated password manager? Or do I need to modify my website (ASP.NET) with a library that will enable the finger print login compatibility?

IMO: Should be less trouble to just make them use the password manager that would be include in the fingerprint scanner package.

What do you guys think of that?

---- Edit ----

I am sorry if I wasn't clear enough, as always, in my head it was clear. Like my wife says: "I am not in your head!" ;)

The general idea was to implement a two factors authentication in the webapp, at first my idea was to implement fingerprint verification. Following my research on the web I find out that fingerprint scanner are not compatible with internet browser other than internet explorer and all my users use chrome or firefox. Moreover, makers of fingerprint scanner do not make them anymore. It seems that the only way to put your hands on a decent scanner is to buy a laptop with the scanner built-in. Following my research I discovered a two factor authentication usb key that will fit 100% of my needs.

Not sure why a made it a monster project with fingerprint scanner when I can simply implement two factor authentication with a simple usb key.

Comment: This question is all over the map. What exactly are you asking? The question of, "what hardware will X software support" is outside the scope of this site. If your question is, "which is better, fingerprints or password managers?" then we need a lot more information or else we are guessing or offering opinions.

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear enough, as always, in my head it was clear. Like my wife says: "we are not in your head!" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that fingerprint scanner are not all compatible with browser, especially when you are not using internet explorer. Moreover, most of them are discontinued at almost all the companies that used to make them... The only considerable reader would be the ones included when you buy a laptop.

The better solution to my problem would be to use a USB two factors authentication key and then use a library in my asp.net code.